# Click on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to simulate clicks on a canvas with javascript\jQuery for testing reasons, but I didn't find a solution. Here's my code:

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
            e.pageX = X[index];
            e.pageY = Y[index];
            $("#gamecanvas").trigger(e);
```

Is it possible to do that ?

For example this [game](http://corehtml5canvas.com/code-live/ch07/example-7.3/example.html) (I searched randomly on the web)   How can I click from JS\jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the event's used on the canvas , whether it's a `click` , `mousedown` , .... etc

In the example you just mentioned , the lucn event uses two event :

One (`mousemove`) for calculating coordinate to get `clientX` and `clientY`

Second (`mousedown`) for lunching ball using last calculated coordinate

So your code should be like :

```
var mousemove = new jQuery.Event("mousemove");
mousemove.clientX = x;//passed valuue
mousemove.clientY =y;//passed valuue

var mousedown = new jQuery.Event("mousedown");

$("#canvas").trigger(mousemove);
$("#canvas").trigger(mousedown);
```

Here a pluncker where I created a script to luanch a ball with passed input coordinate or jus throw the ball in the basket directly :)

See here [livePlunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/lemePS9Ibkvq6e194WkS/)

See url code [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lemePS9Ibkvq6e194WkS?p=preview)

Hope this will help :

Answer (score 1):

This example may help you

```js
$('#canvas_element').on("mousedown mouseup", function(e) {
    $('#output').text($('#output').text() + (e.type + " event fired at coords: " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY));
});

    x_coord = 1;
    y_coord = 1;

    var e = jQuery.Event( "mousedown", { pageX: x_coord, pageY: y_coord } );
    $('#canvas_element').trigger(e);

    // execute more code

    var e = jQuery.Event( "mouseup", { pageX: 255, pageY: 255 } );
    $('#canvas_element').trigger(e);
```

[working link](http://jsfiddle.net/gAxHe/3/)

Comment: For example this game (I searched randomly on the web)  http://corehtml5canvas.com/code-live/ch07/example-7.3/example.html How can I click from JS\jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, pageX and pageY doesn't get the coordinates of the canvas, I had the same issue my self when trying to create a signature pad.

use this instead:

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
           //for IE, safari, opera, chrome
           if(e.offsetX != null) {
            e.offsetX= X[index];
            e.offsetY= Y[index];
          }
          //for firefox
              if(e.layerX!= null) {
            e.layerX= X[index];
            e.layery= Y[index];
          }
            $("#gamecanvas").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score -1):

Without know you use case the documentation for jQuery tells me yes:
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Why you don't search by your self through the very well documented API for jquery?

Comment: It's not about jQuery... it's about a method to click on a canvas with javascript.  If I use the screen coordinates, it doesn't work.

Comment: Might as well answer: why don't you just go study and answer your own question? I mean, this platform isn't really meant for Q&A, come on...